# How Can I Incluse a js file in a Sharepoint MasterPage

Tags: list, javascript, anonymous-authentication

I am newbie about developing with sharepoint and recently, my boss has assigned me a task, so I had to create a list in sharepoint and that list should be accessed by anonymous users. So far everything is fine and I am able to include and see items on that list. But I am facing a problem that is making me nervous.

If I include a js file (jquery library) in a master page, when I try to access these library as an anonymous user, the browser requests a user and password to access the list.

If I remove the js script from the master page, everything works fine.

Is it not possible to include a js file in a master page, even though I have had enabled anonymous access?

P.s: I enabled anonymous access but just for this specific list.

Comment: Where are you storing the JS files ?

Comment: Hi, I am storing the js file in a folder "Scripts". I added this folder in my solution and then I deployed the solution using Visual Studio. When I opened the site with Sharepoint Designer, I can see this folder.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to check:

1. Anonymous users should have access to the library where you are storing JS files otherwise SharePoint will ask for credentials
2. JS files are checked-in and published

Comment: The js files are all checked-in and published. The thing is that I guess i should had set this folder for anonymous access, or perhaps include this and also other js files in library also with anonymous access, as sugested above.

Comment: If you are deploying files using Visual Studio, you can deploy them in Layouts folder and reference from there (`/_layouts/folderName/fileName.js`). This will not require giving any permissions to Anonymous users

Comment: I thought the same thing, but as I am going to repeat this scenario at Office365, I do not know if it will work. This solution must work on Sharepoint Server and Sharepoint Online.

What I thought is to create a separated library and set it with anonymous access and then store the js files.

Comment: You are right, AFAIK in Office 365 layouts folder is not accessible for deployment